# Accessing files from S3 (mounted to EC2) using apache

Tags: apache, amazon-s3, amazon-ec2, ubuntu-10.04

I am observing that accessing files which is present on s3 mounted to ubuntu EC2 is little slow, when compared to accessing files from ubuntu EC2 itself - through apache.

My configuration is ,

S3 bucket  -> Ubuntu EC2 (s3 mounted through s3fs on this machine) . Apache is running on EC2 , and files are accessed using Apache.

What i have observed is, if the request to server is valid ( i.e proper file request) - server takes time to reply, where is some error requests such as file not found or access denied requests are honored immediately.

My question is, has anybody had problems while accessing files sitting S3 buckets when they are mounted to EC2 through apache ( i know i could do cloudfront, but that doesn't serve my purpose as i need to protect files from unwanted access - that's why i have apache rules in place).

Any pointers are greatly helpful.

Thanks.

Comment: If you need to protect files from unwanted access, have you considered setting them to private in S3 and generating presigned authorised URLs? It's easy to generate these URLs using the AWS SDKs. See also http://s3.amazonaws.com/doc/s3-developer-guide/RESTAuthentication.html
Of course, I don't know whether this fits your requirements, but I find pre-signing S3 requests a very good way to protect files from unwanted access.

Comment: Thanks for the reply. But  i already have separate set of authentication process setup using apache. Earlier my files were in my servers , now i moved them to s3 for load balancing, all that stuff. Now all i need is to access those s3 files using apache. I am able to access the files , but its really slow.

Answer (score 0):

Don't use S3 for that. Use NAS!

Comment: Thanks for the reply. But using NAS woudln't server my purpose, i also need to think on load balancing side.

Comment: You can load balance your NAS.